# iOS Firebase Facebook authentication error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am integrating `Facebook` login with `Firebase` in my `iOS` app.

I have followed all steps mentioned here: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login

I make sure that `Facebook` sign in is enabled on `Firebase` and that App ID and App secret are identical to those on `Facebook` developers project settings. I have also added `OAuth redirect URI` to project settings on `Facebook` developers.

When I try to login, `FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult` is correct. It returns nil error and there is an access token returned back.

The problem is when I try to authenticate this user with `Firebase`:

```
let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // ...
            return
        }
        // User is signed in
        // ...
        // User is signed in
    }
```

It always returns this error message:

```
message = "Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {\"error\":{\"message\":\"Invalid OAuth access token signature.\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":190,\"fbtrace_id\":\"ELDLAecGcTE\"}}";
```

I have tried many solutions and all in vain. I have also converted my app status to Live and used Test User account created on Facebook developers page and still get the same error.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

did you validate your Key to get the token?

```
token response
```

you're missing one step maybe check again, it shouldn't happend

Comment: How I can do that ?

Comment: follow every step on the guide, I'm sorry I haven't use facebook Auth, only Push notifications, and I read the guide and it is kinda similar, select your project - > set URL Scheme on info(on the top bar) - > URL types  press the (+) add the link

Comment: check every step carefully Google provides everything you need to get started

Comment: It is fixed now. I just had a mistake in my Facebook App secret key.